# Не запускается приложение в эмуляторе Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Эмулятор запускается, но в своем обычном режиме, то есть с рабочим столом, а приложения как будто и нет.
Притом подключала свое устройство через usb и тестировала на нем и такой проблемы нет
Ошибок никаких не выдает

Answer (score 0):

А эмулятор соответствует требованиям приложения? Версия, разрядность и пр. Да и сам эмулятор может подвисать, попробуйте поискать свое приложение в меню. AS довольно прожорлив.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, это должно решить вашу проблему. После нажатия на Wipe Data жмём Yes.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]